# Character stream processing in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

What is the best way to process text on a character by character basis in C#? I want to be able to handle unicode properly, so I cannot just read a character at a time. It would also be preferable to not have to load the entire string at once before processing it. There appears to be very little information about handling this properly.

Is there a simple way to read an entire character taking into account surrogate pairs and unicode normalization?

Comment: Doing that *without* reading the whole string into memory is going to be really tricky. It's going to be hard enough even *with* the whole string in memory - I suggest you start off with that, and then once you've got that working you move on to trying to stream the data.

Comment: Even if I read the whole file, I haven't been able to find any real information on how to handle surrogate pairs properly in C#.

Comment: Have a look at `System.Globalization.StringInfo`. That deals with graphemes, which may be what you want. It's definitely not made as easy as it might be...

Comment: It seems that assembling surrogate pairs can be done with a minimal state machine, though that leaves you with 20-bit characters. Is your plan to convert to UTF-32? Does [`String.Normalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ppud=4) help you with normalization? Since normalization may involve reordering of characters, e.g. combining characters, it can't be done a character at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have decided to use the System.Globalization.StringInfo class. At some point I may handle this manually. The source code for this feature in mono doesn't look too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), which allows an encoding to be set and read 1 character each time.

Comment: No, it allows you to read one UTF-16 code unit at a time. That's not the same as a Unicode character, when it comes to surrogate pairs.